# Can't change hard link change in PHP

Tags: php, pdftk, php-pdftk

function is that it have to read pdf and print it, but i can't change hard link `<a href="./isakymas/<?php echo $_GET['link'];?>"` all function looks like this - `

```
<h1>Aciu <?php echo $_GET['fname'];?>, jusu PDF jau sugeneruotas, <a href="./completed/<?php echo $_GET['link'];?>" download>Atsisiųsti paspaudus čia</a></h1> 

<div class="clearfix mb-5"></div>
```

```
<h1>Aciu <?php echo $_GET['fname'];?>, jusu PDF jau sugeneruotas, <a href="./isakymas/<?php echo $_GET['link'];?>" download>Atsisiųsti paspaudus čia</a></h1> 

<div class="clearfix mb-5"></div>

<a href="prasymas.php" class="btn btn-success">Sugeneruoti kita PDF </a>
```

` , when i change to "completed" it works correctly, when i press download my link is [Link][3] and it should be "localhost/123/completed/pdf_PRASYMAS instead of /pdf_isakymas". Any ideas how to change it?

Comment: Don't post code or text as images. All code/text must be included in the question as text.

Comment: Sorry about that, next time i'll do it correct way, thanks!

Comment: You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71349317/edit) _this_ question to follow the guidelines, not just "next time".

Comment: What is the page you're trying to load this on?
Does it have a [query parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) named 'link' that's fileld?

Comment: It don't have query parameter that's why i can't figure out, how to do it, logically i could take href="pdf..." but it would take only 1 specific item, that's why i cant use it, because my code is generating new item everytime.